# use of + followed by :: (scope resolution operator in C++ code

Tags: c++, scope-resolution-operator

I have following C++ code snippet :

```
inline std::vector<std::unique_ptr<xir::Tensor>> cloneTensorBuffer(
    const std::vector<const xir::Tensor*>& tensors)
{
    auto ret = std::vector<std::unique_ptr<xir::Tensor>>{};
    auto type = +::DataType::XINT;
    ret.reserve(tensors.size());
    for (const auto& tensor : tensors) {
        ret.push_back(std::unique_ptr<xir::Tensor>(xir::Tensor::create(
            tensor->get_name(), tensor->get_shape(), xir::DataType{type, 8u})));
    }
    return ret;
}
```

I am not clear about the statement:

```
auto type = +::DataType::XINT;
```

What is meant by `+` followed by `::`(scope resolution operator)?

Answer (score 8):

The combination has no special meaning. `+` is the regular prefix operator. In this particular case it’s probably redundant, or performs coercion to `int`. However, the actual meaning might differ depending on how it’s overloaded for the type of `::DataType::XINT`.

And `::` is regular scope resolution operator. When used at the beginning of a sub-expression (i.e. without a left-hand operand), it causes lookup to be performed *at the top scope*, i.e. it ignores any shadowing redefinition of `DataType` in a nested scope:

```
int x = 1;

void f() {
    int x = 2;
    std::cout << "inner = " << x << "\n";   // inner = 2
    std::cout << "outer = " << ::x << "\n"; // outer = 1
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I know what is scope resolution operator but was not clear about +:: and was wondering if +:: has any special meaning.

Answer (score 4):

There is no `+::`. Its the unary `+` operator and `::` operator.

`::foo` refers to `foo` in the global namespace. It might be necessary when there is another `DataTye::XINT` in the current namespace.

The unary `+` is sometimes used to trigger implicit conversions. You need to check what type `::DataType::XINT` is and what conversions it has available.

As I don't know what `::DataType::XINT` is, here is an example with a lambda expression:

```
template <typename T>
void foo();

int main() {
    auto x = [](){};
    foo(x);
    foo(+x);
}
```

Error message (shortened) is:

```
<source>:6:8: error: no matching function for call to 'foo(main()::<lambda()>&)'
    6 |     foo(x);
<source>:7:8: error: no matching function for call to 'foo(void (*)())'
    7 |     foo(+x);
      |     ~~~^~~~
```

You can see that `foo(x)` tries to call `foo` with the lambda, while in `foo(+x)` the lambda was implicitly converted to a function pointer (because of `ClosureType::operator ret(*)(params)()` and `+` being available for function pointers but not for the lambdas type).